# Sending all electron HTTP requests through a proxy.

Tags: javascript, electron, http-proxy

How can I send all HTTP requests made from electron through a custom proxy? I have an electron app making requests to various 3rd party services like Firebase, Mixpanel etc. I want these requests to be routed through a HTTP proxy that I configure inside electron. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by using the WebRequest class provided by electron from within the **main process**.
https://electronjs.org/docs/all#webrequestonbeforerequestfilter-listener

An example of this where all request urls are printed to the console:

```
const {session} = require('electron')

// IMPORTANT: place this after the ready event
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders({urls:'*'}, (details, callback) => {
  console.log(details.url)
})
```